# Setting two adapters to the same list

Tags: android, listview, adapter

My app download text and image from sever and display them in list i use two separate adapters one for text and another for image . i cannot put them in same adapter and also i cannot put both of adapters in same list . so how to connect two adapters with same list
that's some of my code for first adapter

```
private class LoadService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String Content;
    private String Error = null;
    private final String TAG = null;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(mainpage.this);

    ImageView imagee = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    String url = "images url";
    String[] img = new String[1000];
    // lv.setAdapter(new ImageLoader(, img));


    protected void onPreExecute() {

        Dialog.setMessage("Loading service..");
        Dialog.show();
        Dialog.dismiss();

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {


            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // Close progress dialog
        Dialog.dismiss();
        Log.e(TAG, "Raw output "
                + Content);


        try {

            // Load json data and display
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(Content);
            JSONArray jre = json.getJSONArray("updates");
             for (int j = 0; j < jre.length(); j++) {

                JSONObject jobject = jre.getJSONObject(j);

                String name11 = jobject.getString("title");
                String description = jobject.getString("description");

                String image = jobject.getString("image");
                String total = url + image;
                img[j] = total;



                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                contact.put("title", name11);
                contact.put("description", description);
                contactList.add(contact);
            }




        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(mainpage.this, ContactList, R.layout.item, new String[]{"title", "description"}, new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.description});

      lv.setAdapter(adapter);}
```

my second adapter

```
 public class loader extends ArrayAdapter {

    public Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

   private String[] img;

    public loader(Context context, String[] img) {
        super(context, R.layout.item, img);

        this.context = context;
        this.img = img;

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

        }
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        Picasso.with(context).load(img[position]).into(imageView);

        return convertView;

    }
```

i set it in list using

```
        loader im=new loader(mainpage.this,img);

        lv.setAdapter(im);
```

sorry for my long code

Comment: Can you show me your output screen ? . You cant connect 2 adapter for same list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Arraylist with model(contains your text and image url as string)  class and pass that arraylist to your adapter. Check out below code:

Create new `Product.java`

```
public class Product{  

 private String yourText = "";
    private String imgUrl= "";


    public String getyourText () {
        return yourText ;
    }

    public void setyourText(String yourText) {
        this.yourText  = yourText 
    }

    public String getimgUrl() {
        return imgUrl;
    }

    public void setimgUrl(String imgUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }

}
```

Now your AsyncTask:

```
private LoaderAdapter mLoaderAdapter;
private ArrayList<Product> mArrayList = null;

Product mProduct;

private class LoadService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String Content;
    private String Error = null;
    private final String TAG = null;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(mainpage.this);

    ImageView imagee = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    String url = "http://phone.tmsline.com/images/uploads/";
    String[] img = new String[1000];
    // lv.setAdapter(new ImageLoader(, img));


    protected void onPreExecute() {

        Dialog.setMessage("Loading service..");
        Dialog.show();
        Dialog.dismiss();

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {


            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // Close progress dialog
        Dialog.dismiss();
        Log.e(TAG, "Raw output "
                + Content);


        try {

            // Load json data and display
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(Content);
            JSONArray jre = json.getJSONArray("updates");

            mArrayList = new ArrayList<Product>();

             for (int j = 0; j < jre.length(); j++) {

                 mProduct = new Product();

                JSONObject jobject = jre.getJSONObject(j);

                String name11 = jobject.getString("title");
                String description = jobject.getString("description");

                String image = jobject.getString("image");
                String fullUrl = url + image;

                 mProduct.setyourText(name11);
                 mProduct.setimgUrl(fullUrl);

                 mArrayList.add(mProduct);

                 mProduct = null;
            }




        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        mLoaderAdapter = new LoaderAdapter (getApplicationContext(),mArrayList);

        lv.setAdapter(mLoaderAdapter);}
```

Finally your adapter class:

```
public class LoaderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

    public Context context;
    private ArrayList<Product> values;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

   private String[] img;

    public loader(Context context, ArrayList<Product> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.item, img);

        this.context = context;
         this.values = values;

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

        }
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);

        Product mProduct = values.get(position);

        textView.setText(mProduct.getyourText());
        Picasso.with(context).load(mProduct.getimgUrl()).into(imageView);

        return convertView;

    }
```

Now you can bind all your text and image on same without with 1 adapter class for same list.

Cheers!!

Comment: there is error in                                                                                          (textView.setText(mProduct.getyourText());)                                                 (   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at commyc.example.blu_ray91111.timslinesoluation.LoaderAdapter.getView(LoaderAdapter.java:51))

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at commyc.example.blu_ray91111.timslinesoluation.LoaderAdapter.getView(LoaderAdapter.java:51)

Comment: have you changed your textview id in `R.id.yourtextview` ??

Comment: yes , "TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item1);"

Comment: Post your item xml.

Comment: Ok. Please accept the answer if its worked for you . :-)

Comment: really i am new in the site how to do that?